# gwt-phonegap code to stop app

Tags: cordova

I am building a mobile app using gwt-phonegap version 1.7. I have tried using ".exitApp" to close my app and it is closing the app and returning to main screen there are no issues till now but When I check the status of the app in "settings > applications > manage applications", my app is still running and "Force stop" option is still active.

May I know is there any other way to close the Android app?
I am using GWT-phonegap to and Mgwt to build my app.

Thanks and Regards,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate method of the class that you extend DroidGap from you will need to add this line:

```
super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", false);
```

That should keep it from running in the background.

Comment: now it's in the config.xml file : <preference name="keepRunning" value="true"/>

Comment: @Simon MacDonald, Maybe set keepRunning at true, doesn't ?